# How to prevent Emacs from native-compiling certain packages?

Tags: osx, native-comp

I am trying to prevent `emacs-jupyter` package from native compilation. There is a known bug that breaks the package when native compiled. [1] I can manually delete the `eln` files in `eln-cache` dir and package starts working. I tried the suggested solutions. Apperently this variable no longer exists,

```
(setq comp-deferred-compilation-deny-list (list "jupyter"))
```

how ever this variable does exists,

```
(add-to-list 'native-comp-deferred-compilation-deny-list ".*emacs-jupyter.*")
```

however I tried various regex expressions to match emacs jupyter but emacs (28.2) seems to be ignoring this variable. Is there a special format to this regex?

[1] https://github.com/nnicandro/emacs-jupyter/issues/297

Comment: I presume that the name of the variable was misspelled in the first case (they just neglected to add the `native-` part). Why don't you try the regexp from it, i.e. just  `"jupyter"`, and see if that works? That's a flying guess mind you.

Answer (score 2):

this is how I use the variable to block compilation of a package (this is on Windows)

```
(setq native-comp-deferred-compilation-deny-list '("worf"))
```

It took a lot of experimentation to get this right.